# $.inArray() returns false -1 even though the variable matches array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am attempting to see that my `currentMedia` variable (which is in the DOM) can be found in my array `media`, then return `i` which should be 0 not -1.

if I run `console.log(media[0]);` and `console.log(currentMedia);` the results are the same but you will notice the colors in chrome, `media[0]` looks like live html where as `currentMedia` returns the exact same text but is greyed out.

my html looks like this:

```
<div class="slideshow">
    <div class="media">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/112x112" style="opacity: 0;">
    </div>
</div>
```

This is a link to the image of the code that is bawking - https://i.stack.imgur.com/6jatc.jpg you will see that the `console.log` values of `media[0]` and `currentMedia` appear to be the same but the `currentImageKey();` function does not return `0` as it should but instead returns `-1`

```
function currentImageKey(i) {
    currentMedia = $(".media").children()[0].outerHTML
    i = $.inArray(currentMedia, media)
    return i;
};
```

this should return 0

```
function currentImageKey(i) {
    currentMedia = $(".media").children()[0].outerHTML
    i = $.inArray(currentMedia, media)
    return i;
};

currentImageKey();

if (currentMedia === $(".media").children()[0].outerHTML ) {
    console.log("equal");
}

if(jQuery.inArray(currentMedia, media) != -1) {
    console.log("is in array");
} else {
    console.log("is NOT in array");
}
```

All this retuns

`equal` 
`is NOT in array`
and
`undefined`

Comment: From a quick glance one variable references the actual DOM element whereas the other references a string with the respective content.

Comment: The value of `.outerHTML` will be a **string**, not DOM nodes, in other words.

Comment: Just remove `.outerHTML` and it should work

Comment: @Pointy How would I write my variable to return the DOM node inside .media element?

Comment: Just use `$(".media").children()[0]` without `.outerHTML`

Comment: Thank you Pointy & Karl! I have been staring at this for way too long

Comment: why was I downvoted for this question?

Answer (score 0):

**As mentioned in the comments:**

Running the $.inArray w/o `.outerHTML` will result in a correct assessment of the array.

.outerHTML is a String type of JS property.

"The outerHTML attribute of the element DOM interface gets the serialized HTML fragment describing the element including its descendants. It can be set to replace the element with nodes parsed from the given string."

see - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.outerHTML

```
function currentImageKey(i) {
currentMedia = $(".media").children()[0]
i = $.inArray(currentMedia, media)
return i;
};

currentImageKey();
```

This will return the correct value with which to compare to the array.